# Error in Xamarin.Forms: "Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base classes"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing an issue in my Xamarin.Forms project, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. I've encountered the following error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0263 Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base classes BeautyFly C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\BeautyFly\BeautyFly\BeautyFly\App.xaml.cs 9 Active
```

Additionally, there is a related error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0103 The name 'MainPage' does not exist in the current context BeautyFly C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\BeautyFly\BeautyFly\BeautyFly\App.xaml.cs 19 Active
```

**Context:**

Project Structure:

Xamarin.Forms project named "BeautyFly"

App.xaml.cs file contains the App class definition

MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs files for the main page of the application

Code Snippets:

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BeautyFly.App">

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="resultEntry" Text="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Text="7" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Text="8" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button Text="9" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Button Text="/" Clicked="OnOperatorClicked" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />

            <Button Text="4" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Text="5" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button Text="6" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Button Text="*" Clicked="OnOperatorClicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />

            <Button Text="1" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Text="2" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button Text="3" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Button Text="-" Clicked="OnOperatorClicked" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" />

            <Button Text="0" Clicked="OnNumberClicked" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button Text="." Clicked="OnDecimalClicked" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button Text="=" Clicked="OnEqualClicked" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Button Text="+" Clicked="OnOperatorClicked" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using BeautyFly.Services;
using BeautyFly.Views;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BeautyFly
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private string currentInput = string.Empty;
        private string currentOperator = string.Empty;
        private double result = 0;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
        private void OnNumberClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            currentInput += button.Text;
            resultEntry.Text = currentInput;
        }

        private void OnOperatorClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            currentOperator = button.Text;
            result = double.Parse(currentInput);
            currentInput = string.Empty;
        }

        private void OnEqualClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double secondOperand = double.Parse(currentInput);

            switch (currentOperator)
            {
                case "+":
                    result += secondOperand;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result -= secondOperand;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result *= secondOperand;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    if (secondOperand != 0)
                        result /= secondOperand;
                    else
                        resultEntry.Text = "Error";
                    break;
            }

            resultEntry.Text = result.ToString();
            currentInput = string.Empty;
        }

        private void OnDecimalClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!currentInput.Contains("."))
            {
                currentInput += ".";
                resultEntry.Text = currentInput;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Checked the inheritance of the App class
Verified the MainPage class and its references

**Questions:**

What could be causing the "Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base classes" error in my App.xaml.cs file?

How can I resolve the "The name 'MainPage' does not exist in the current context" error?

Are there any specific areas of my code that I should review to identify and fix this issue?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've replaced the contents of your *App.xaml*.

Your *App.xaml*'s root element should be `<Application>`. You cannot specify a different base type, meaning that the base class of `App` must be `Application` in both XAML and code-behind.

*App.xaml* and *App.xaml.cs* are the entry point of your app and do not have their own UI. Instead, you need to set the `MainPage` property of the `App` class to a *NavigationPage*, *ContentPage* or *AppShell*.

The `App` class hosts the application and its content and the *App.xaml* part of it should only hold declarations, like styles and such:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="BeautyFly.App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      
      <!-- global converters, styles, etc. go here -->      
      
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now, you should either have or create a *MainPage.xaml* and *MainPage.xaml.cs* (simply add a new *ContentPage* to your project and call it *MainPage* in the wizard).

Then, in your *App.xaml.cs* you can either set the *MainPage* class directly as the `MainPage` of the app or wrap it in a *NavigationPage*, e.g.:

```cs
using BeautyFly.Services;
using BeautyFly.Views;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BeautyFly
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            //or:
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the difference between the `MainPage` property (part of the `Application` base class) and the `MainPage` class you need to create, if you haven't already. The name `MainPage` is not mandatory nor conventional, you can choose any appropriate name for it.

If you want to use [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/create), you do as you already have it, but then you need to register your MainPage class with Shell (see link).

```cs
using BeautyFly.Services;
using BeautyFly.Views;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BeautyFly
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }
}
```

The important take-away here is that *App.xaml* and *App.xaml.cs* need to specify the same base class (= `Application`), because they're two parts of the same class.

Comment: Can i use `AppShell` instead of creating `MainPage`?

Comment: AppShell is just a shell, you need at least one ContentPage and if you only use a single ContentPage, then there is no navigation and without navigation, you don't need AppShell. Like I mentioned, you need some content and it doesn't have to be called MainPage. However, if you use AppShell, you still need some ContentPages to populate the ShellContent as described under the link to the official documentation of Xamarin.Forms Shell.

Comment: I don't know what you're saying... . I created `MainPage` file and put codes you said before but i got error. i'm new to Xamarin I don't understand most of things.